# Getting ack to search through .htaccess or other dotfiles

Tags: perl, .htaccess, ack, dotfiles

Is there any way to get ack to search through a file whose filename starts with a `.` (e.g. .htaccess), without resorting to the `--all` or `--unrestricted` options?

I've tried adding the following to my `~/.ackrc` file to no avail:

```
--type-set=apache=.htaccess
```

Answer (score 5):

It would appear that ack doesn't recognize a filename that's all extension; that is, when you specify an extension of ".htaccess", ack only looks for files with at least one character before that extension.

To get around this, you can use `-u/--unrestricted` in combination with the `-G regex` flag (to restrict the search to files whose names match a regex).  For example:

```
$ ack -u -G '\.htaccess' pattern
```

Comment: To configure in `.ackrc`, place `-u` and `-G/\.(bash_aliases|bash_history|bashrc)$` (for example) on *separate lines*. The missing space after `-G` is significant. The advantage is that you don't need to add these parameters and it doesn't search through `.orig` files and the like. The downside is of course when you *don't* want to use the `-u` option.

Comment: Note: this doesn't seem to work with ack 2 - `ack -u -G '\.htaccess' pattern #
Option '-u' is not valid in ack 2`, and without the -u it says -G is not a valid option either

Answer (score 1):

### Updated @Sean's answer for Ack 2

since they removed the two flags that @Sean used

[ack 2 release notes](http://beyondgrep.com/ack-2.0/) say:

> The -G option has been removed. Two patterns on the command line was
>   ambiguous. In this command line:
>
> ```
> ack1 -G filepattern -i -w searchpattern
> ```
>
> which pattern does -i and -w modify? Now, with ack 2.0, you can use
>   the new -x to pipe filenames from one invocation of ack into another.
>
> ```
> ack2 -g -i filepattern | ack2 -x -w searchpattern
> ```

and the -u (unrestricted) flag is not needed any more. So what you want is:

```
ack -g "\.htaccess" | ack -x pattern
```

Or, for that matter, just use [find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) to generate the file list (especially useful to find a file in a dotfolder):

```
find **/.hidden/complex-path/* | ack -x pattern
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in ack 1.x.  ack 2.0 will have more flexible ways of specifying files.